# Api python de telegram bot no actualiza con getUpdates()

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram.bot

estoy preparando un bot de telegram con python usando telegram-bot. Existe el método getUpdates() que teóricamente, sin parámetros adicionales, devuelve las 100 últimas entradas que el bot tenga, tanto si es un grupo, un canal o un chat privado entre el usuario y el bot.

Con esto en mente, hago una llamada al método mencionado y devuelve todo el rato lo mismo, aunque yo escriba al bot en un canal o en privado

Aquí el código

```
  bot = telegram.Bot(token=core.telegramToken)
  objUpdt = bot.getUpdates()
  lista = []
  
  for upd in objUpdt:
    for post in [upd]:
      print ("tipo = ", type(post['channel_post']['text']))
      if (type(post['channel_post']['text']) != 'NoneType'):
       print("--",post['channel_post']['text'])
       #lista.append(post['channel_post']['text'])
```

NOTA:La variable **lista** se usa luego para extraer el último registro y trabajarlo

Pues bien, esto produce siempre esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como puede verse en esta imagen, el chat tiene otras entradas distintas, pues se ha eliminado el mensaje BEAR - BTCUPUSDT por si ese carácter extraño de la primera imagen pudiera dar problemas y también se ha añadido texto nuevo después.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo así toda la mañana y no encuentro en la docu de Telegram.org nada que haga referencia a este problema, incluso he buscado a ver si telegram.org tuviera foros para desarrollo, pero tampoco he encontrado nada, sólo su documentación

A alguien le ha pasado esto? O tiene alguna idea de por dónde pueden ir los tiros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pues me respondo a mi misma ahora que he dado con la solución.

Mi código es correcto en todos sus puntos. Mi problema surgía en el momento que intentaba acceder a "channel_post" de la variable post. Resulta que telegram diferencia entre "channel_post" y "message", según si el mensaje lo ha escrito un usuario (administrador o no) (channel_post) o lo ha escrito un robot (message)

En mi caso particular intentaba acceder a mensajes de un robot pero usando el índice para mensajes de usuarios, por lo que daba error todas las veces.

Gracias a @marcelo-graef porque aunque no me dio la solución en sí, sí me ha ayudado a investigar mejor los datos retornados y al final eso es lo que me ha permitido detectar esa diferencia y reprogramar lo necesario.

Answer (score 3):

Hice las siguientes pruebas, y en objeto "post" no es un dict, sino un

```
<class 'telegram.update.Update'>
```

por lo tanto no deja acceder a sus atributos como un dict.

Usando **`dir(post)`** pude ver que posee una funcion **`to_dict()`**, y con esa ya permite ingresar a los datos.

No tiene el campo **`channel_post`**, pero tiene **`update_id`** y **`message`** (este ultimo posee muchos datos).

Acá va la parte de código que use:

```
for upd in objUpdt:
    for post in [upd]:
        print(type(post))
        print(dir(post))
        post_dict = post.to_dict()
```

Comment: El objeto objUpdt devuelve estos valores: objUpdt = {'update_id': 951104135,
'channel_post': {'message_id': 6,
'date': 1604499342,
'chat': {'id': -1001324085073,
'type': 'channel',
'title': 'TV ALERTS'},
'text': 'pelele',
'entities': [],
'caption_entities': [],
'photo': [],
'new_chat_members': [],
'new_chat_photo': [],
'delete_chat_photo': False,
'group_chat_created': False,
'supergroup_chat_created': False,
'channel_chat_created': False}}

Es a partir de esto de donde sale el "channel_post" que hemos visto los dos, ya que "message" contiene dentro el "channel_post"

Comment: De todos modos @marcelo, el problema no viene por el contenido retornado, sino que el método getUpdates() devuelve info que no es real. Este punto lo detallo en las imágenes